# AmCharts4: getPolygonById method for custom map from GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, amcharts, amcharts4

I am attempting to use the getPolygonById method with a map polygon series created using custom GeoJSON data (this is in order to zoom to a polygon with a specific ID). I have followed the instructions provided on [creating custom maps](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-custom-maps/#Identifying_properties).

The Map Polygon Series from the custom GeoJSON data renders and events function correctly (eg to zoom to a polygon or color change on "hit").

However, when calling customSeries.getPolygonById("ExampleID"), the method returns "undefined".  Note that the GeoJSON source for customSeries includes the corresponding id field (ie "id": "ExampleID").

That is, despite rendering correctly, the following code returns "undefined":

```
var customSeries = map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
customSeries.geodataSource.url = "/geojson/customSeries.geojson";
customSeries.useGeodata = true;
console.log(customSeries.getPolygonById("ExampleID"));
```

This contrasts with the return of the JSON object with specified Map Polygon when using an Amcharts map template. For example, the following code returns an object corresponding to the Map Polygon with "US" id:

```
var worldLow = map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries();
worldLow.useGeodata = true;
worldLow.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow; 
console.log(worldLow.getPolygonById("US"));
```

Is this an issue with my data? Or is something additional required to call getPolygonById on a Map Polygon Series from custom GeoJSON?

Answer (score 0):

Loading data through the DataSource / GeoDataSource object is done asynchronously, so your `getPolygonById` call is executing before the data has been parsed and loaded into the series. You can either use the `done` event in the DataSource or `datavalidated` event in the series to check for whether the data has been loaded before calling `getPolygonById`

```
polygonSeries.geodataSource.events.on('done', function() {
  // timeout needed as the data isn't complately loaded at this point
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('done: ', polygonSeries.getPolygonById('BCH'))
  }, 100)
})
// OR
polygonSeries.events.on('datavalidated', function() {
  // check if there's data loaded in the array before looking up
  // the polygon
  if (polygonSeries.data.length) {
    console.log('data loaded', polygonSeries.getPolygonById('BCH'))
  }
})
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/40323e660f291ed800b061043e786f9c?editors=0010)

Comment: This is very helpful and thanks for this clarification!

Comment: Three follow-up questions: (1) Is there AmCharts documentation relating to the event listener for geodataSource and/or the dataValidated event? (2) I understand that "dataValidated" only registers on a change in the data - and therefore the event won't trigger if the data has already validated? (3) Can one use async/await to await the addition of the geodata?

Comment: 1: Yes, several: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/
and https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/#Handling_events along with class-specific documentation in the reference section. 2: It fires whenever the data needs to be re-parsed, which includes initilization and on change. 3. No.